# Flutter Parse Json

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Please, is anyone able to help me to parse this json? I only need the "RelatedTopics" part... I am trying first to decode the string returned from the API and then parse it...
I am not sure why I am not able to but this is the full json endpoint: http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=simpsons+characters&format=json

```
{
   "Abstract":"",
   "AbstractSource":"Wikipedia",
   "AbstractText":"",
   "AbstractURL":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Simpsons_characters",
   "Answer":"",
   "AnswerType":"",
   "Definition":"",
   "DefinitionSource":"",
   "DefinitionURL":"",
   "Entity":"",
   "Heading":"The Simpsons characters",
   "Image":"",
   "ImageHeight":0,
   "ImageIsLogo":0,
   "ImageWidth":0,
   "Infobox":"",
   "Redirect":"",
   "RelatedTopics":[
      {
         "FirstURL":"https://duckduckgo.com/Apu_Nahasapeemapetilan",
         "Icon":{
            "Height":"",
            "URL":"",
            "Width":""
         },
         "Result":"<a href=\"https://duckduckgo.com/Apu_Nahasapeemapetilan\">Apu Nahasapeemapetilan</a><br>Apu Nahasapeemapetilan is a recurring character in the American animated television series The Simpsons. He is an Indian immigrant proprietor who runs the Kwik-E-Mart, a popular convenience store in Springfield, and is known for his catchphrase, \"Thank you, come again\".",
         "Text":"Apu Nahasapeemapetilan - Apu Nahasapeemapetilan is a recurring character in the American animated television series The Simpsons. He is an Indian immigrant proprietor who runs the Kwik-E-Mart, a popular convenience store in Springfield, and is known for his catchphrase, \"Thank you, come again\"."
      },
      {
         "FirstURL":"https://duckduckgo.com/Apu_Nahasapeemapetilon",
         "Icon":{
            "Height":"",
            "URL":"/i/99b04638.png",
            "Width":""
         },
         "Result":"<a href=\"https://duckduckgo.com/Apu_Nahasapeemapetilon\">Apu Nahasapeemapetilon</a><br>Apu Nahasapeemapetilon is a recurring character in the American animated television series The Simpsons. He is an Indian immigrant proprietor who runs the Kwik-E-Mart, a popular convenience store in Springfield, and is known for his catchphrase, \"Thank you, come again\".",
         "Text":"Apu Nahasapeemapetilon - Apu Nahasapeemapetilon is a recurring character in the American animated television series The Simpsons. He is an Indian immigrant proprietor who runs the Kwik-E-Mart, a popular convenience store in Springfield, and is known for his catchphrase, \"Thank you, come again\"."
      },
   ],
   "Results":[
      
   ],
   "Type":"C",
   "meta":{
      "attribution":null,
      "blockgroup":null,
      "created_date":null,
      "description":"Wikipedia",
      "designer":null,
      "dev_date":null,
      "dev_milestone":"live",
      "developer":[
         {
            "name":"DDG Team",
            "type":"ddg",
            "url":"http://www.duckduckhack.com"
         }
      ],
      "example_query":"nikola tesla",
      "id":"wikipedia_fathead",
      "is_stackexchange":null,
      "js_callback_name":"wikipedia",
      "live_date":null,
      "maintainer":{
         "github":"duckduckgo"
      },
      "name":"Wikipedia",
      "perl_module":"DDG::Fathead::Wikipedia",
      "producer":null,
      "production_state":"online",
      "repo":"fathead",
      "signal_from":"wikipedia_fathead",
      "src_domain":"en.wikipedia.org",
      "src_id":1,
      "src_name":"Wikipedia",
      "src_options":{
         "directory":"",
         "is_fanon":0,
         "is_mediawiki":1,
         "is_wikipedia":1,
         "language":"en",
         "min_abstract_length":"20",
         "skip_abstract":0,
         "skip_abstract_paren":0,
         "skip_end":"0",
         "skip_icon":0,
         "skip_image_name":0,
         "skip_qr":"",
         "source_skip":"",
         "src_info":""
      },
      "src_url":null,
      "status":"live",
      "tab":"About",
      "topic":[
         "productivity"
      ],
      "unsafe":0
   }
}
```

My model is:

```
class MyModel {
    final String? firstUrl;
    final Icon? icon;
    final String? result;
    final String? text;

    MyModel({
        this.firstUrl,
        this.icon,
        this.result,
        this.text,
    });

}

class Icon {
    final String? height;
    final String? url;
    final String? width;

    Icon({
        this.height,
        this.url,
        this.width,
    });

}
```

This is what I am doing but it is not working:

```
Future<List<MyModel>> fetchData() async {
    final response = await client.get(AppEndpoints.myurl);
    final data = jsonDecode(response.data);
    final res = data['RelatedTopics'];
    final myData = MyModel.fromJson(res);
    return [myData];
  }
```

Any help is very welcome...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to parse the data by doing this:

```
Future<List<MyModel>> fetchData() async {
    final response = await client.get(AppEndpoints.myUrl);
    final data = jsonDecode(response.data);
    print(data['RelatedTopics']);
    return List<MyModel>.from(
        data['RelatedTopics'].map((x) => MyModel.fromJson(x)));
```